# Handle Apostrophe in NSPredicate Array search

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm searching an Array by merchant Name using CONTAIN term of NSPredicate, it is working expect one thing.

One of merchant name is Tortilla's and if user search with Apostrophe it returns 0 results.
Following is code i'm using for search

```
NSArray *terms = [searchText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

for(NSString *term in terms) {
    if([term length] == 0) { continue; }
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.merchant_name contains[cd] %@", term];
    [subpredicates addObject:p];
}

NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
self.myCouponsSearchArray = [NSArray array];
self.myCouponsSearchArray = [self.myCouponsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

if my search term is only tortilla it returns exactly correct results, but as soon as Apostrophe come in play it returns wrong results

Comment: Are you sure the character for the apostrophe is the same in both cases?

Comment: [cd] match is for that reason that it matches Diacritic characters

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne does diacritic match U+0027, U+2018 and U+2019 as the same thing?

Comment: Tortilla’s this is merchant_name in array

Comment: `’` and `'` are not the same character.

Comment: i'm not sure if i can force user to write special kind of Apostrophe, any way to handle this situation ?